# How can I remove the shadow from a text box

Tags: css

I want to remove the white edges and the black shadow from my text box in the page of https://help.penny.co/portal/en/home:
Here's what I tried:

```
.SearchBox__searchpart{
background-color:transparent;
   box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

This is the input text CSS:

```
.SearchBox__searchpart input {
  background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #818a91;
    vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 24px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your HTML, including any other CSS that may be affecting your element including imported stylesheets etc? It's not possible to discern why your box shadow property is not working as expected.

Comment: @CalvinTiley This is the home page showing the text box https://help.penny.co/portal/en/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shadow that you see is applied to `#searchContainer`, try this in your stylesheet:

```
#searchContainer {
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. How did you figure this out if I may ask?

Comment: I encourage you to use the inspection tool in your browser, it will help you inspect your HTML elements along with the CSS. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're targeting the wrong element. The element with box shadow in the website you posted is the element with the class `Header__searchLink`. If you set `box-shadow: none;` on that element, you'll achieve nirvana.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the parent of the input element and and a css box-shadow: none; there.
Next time you ask, please add more details so that you can find answers easily.